# After loading of XML-definition-file for WPF the bindings don't refresh

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

We are making a designer application for WPF in which the user can drop controls on a WPF window and adjust the bindings by a dialogue where he can set the `Source` and the `Path` properties.
After the user finished a new WPF window he could serialize it to an XML file including the bindings ([XamlWriter-and-Bindings-Serialization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27158/XamlWriter-and-Bindings-Serialization)).

When the user wants to use the new window, the XML-file will be loaded in a new WPF window, restoring the controls and their bindings by the saved Definition.

To test this, we have made a test project in which we create in a WPF window (in code-behind) and a `DataTable` as `DataSource` and controls, which are bound to that `DataSource`.
We have just a minimal `ViewModel` with a property of type `DataSet` which contains the `DataTable`.
When we save the WPF window as XML, the controls and bindings are written to the XML file like that:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=[0][Name], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="120" Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="10" />
```

In another 'testwindow' we created the `DataSource` and loaded the XML file so that the controls and the bindings would be recreated, but it seems to be that the bindings were not refreshed.
The `TextBox` above is empty.

We tried to refresh it with `XmlDataProvider`, but it doesn't work.

```
XmlDataProvider provider = new XmlDataProvider();
provider = (XmlDataProvider)this.DataContext;
provider.Refresh();
```

How can we refresh the bindings?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say "XML-definition-file for WPF", you probably mean XAML. Then you would use `XamlReader` for deserialization, instead of `XmlDataProvider`. [`XamlReader.Load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup(v=vs.110).aspx) would parse a piece of XAML and return the root object of that XAML.

Comment: Thanks a lot Clemens! Meanwhile we have found out that it works fine in the testwindow, when the DataContext gets the DataTable and not the ViewModel. Normally we have in our ViewModel a DataSet property in which the DataTables are lying. Can the Binding be adjusted, so that the Binding gets the DataTable out of the ViewModel's DataSet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to resolve that problem.

1. The DataContext-property of the WPF-window gets the DataTable or it's DataView-version (-> datatable.DefaultView). But this means to have only one datatable in the WPF-window.
2. Create CustomControls with an additional DependencyProperty to store the name of the DataTable to which controls are bound. After the XML-file from the serialization was reloaded, walk through all controls, check with reflection if they have the property (if (frameworkelement.GetType().GetProperty(propertyname) != null) and set the DataContext-property of the control with the DataTable or DataView. In that case it's possible with many datatables.